# Drag-and-drop event which has two different meanings depending on where to drop it

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, collision-detection, overlap, sortablejs

I'm looking for a way to represent that a drag-and-drop event has two different meanings depending on where to drop an item.
My goal is to make a pictorial dictionary, such as in this image:

[image: schematics of my goal]

When a item (a text) in the right column is dropped within the right column, the item is sorted with Sortable.JS; while when dropped in the left column, the item is free from Sortable.JS just to be on an image.

Features that the columns should have:

- Left column: Unsortable and droppable (That is, Images are unsortable, but text is droppable on an image.)
- Right column: Texts are sortable.
- Each column has one independent scroll bar.

Based on [a sample code using Sortable.JS](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists), I could have a code which allows Drag-and-drop between left and right columns, each column has one independent scroll bar.

Next, I found [another example code to add draggable text on image in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562948/how-to-add-draggable-text-on-image-in-javascript), and then I ported it into the former code, and wrote the following code.

However, the left column is undroppable. Help me, please.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="shared-lists" class="row">
                <div id="column-left" class="filtered" style="width:200px;height:300px;overflow:auto;">
                    <div ><img src="./assets/fish.png"></div>
                    <div ><img src="./assets/car.png"></div>
                    <div ><img src="./assets/apple.png"></div>
                    <div ><img src="./assets/umbrella.png"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="column-right" class="list-group col" style="width:100px;height:180px;overflow:auto;">
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">umbrella</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">apple</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">car</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">school</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">fish</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">pen</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item tinted">flower</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.10.1/Sortable.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var columnRight = document.getElementById('column-right');
            new Sortable(columnRight, {
                group: 'shared',
                animation: 100,
            });

            var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
            x_pos = 0,
            y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
            x_elem = 0,
            y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

            // Will be called when user starts dragging an element
            function _drag_init(elem) {
                // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
                selected = elem;
                x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
                y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
            }

            // Will be called when user dragging an element
            function _move_elem(e) {
                x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
                y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;

                if (selected !== null) {
                    selected.screenX = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
                    selected.screenY = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
                }
            }

            // Destroy the object when we are done
            function _destroy() {
                selected = null;
            }

            // Bind the functions...
            document.onmousedown = _drag_init;
            document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
            document.onmouseup = _destroy;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SeeSharper - Thanks for your update my sentences. How kind of you to help me.